# issues with mysql code

Tags: python, mysql

the solutions here are really useful. I am kinda stocked with getting around my code. forgive any silly questions as i am new to mysql. I tried running this code and gets stocked with "cursor.execute(sql,tuple(args))"

```
def back_pack(cursor, sql, args=[]):
  rowLst = []
  if args == []:
      cursor.excute(sql)
  else:
      cursor.execute(sql,tuple(args))
  columnlst=zip(*cursor.description)[0]
```

and i get an error of : _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use cursor.execute(sql,tuple(args)).

Comment: sql=("""SELECT  catalogue_master.sourceName,...""")

Comment: yes, the `...` is not correct sql. So try to repair your statement.

Answer (score 1):

i called it using;
    rowLst = back_pack(cursor, sql, [args]) and it flags that error.

```
args = (srcDict[sourceName]['DecWcent_deg'],
        srcDict[sourceName]['DecWcent_deg'],
        srcDict[sourceName]['RAwcent_hr']*15.0,
        srcDict[sourceName]['DecWcent_deg'],
        srcDict[sourceName]['DecWcent_deg'],
        srcDict[sourceName]['RAwcent_hr']*15.0,
        srchRad_deg,
        sourceName)
sql = """SELECT
catalogue_master.sourceName,
catalogue_master.l_deg,
catalogue_master.b_deg,                                                     
catalogue_master.RAwcent_hr,
catalogue_master.DecWcent_deg,
catalogue_master.mergeFlux_mJy,
catalogue_master.mergeAngscaleAbs_asec,
catalogue_master.gaussMajorAxCor_asec,
catalogue_master.gaussMinorAxCor_asec,
catalogue_master.gaussPosangle_deg,
catalogue_master.mType,
catalogue_poly.polySrc,
degrees(acos(cos(radians(90-%s))
*cos(radians(90-catalogue_master.DecWcent_deg))
+sin(radians(90-%s))
*sin(radians(90-catalogue_master.DecWcent_deg))
*cos(radians(catalogue_master.RAwcent_hr*15-%s))))
as dist
FROM catalogue_master LEFT JOIN catalogue_poly
ON catalogue_master.sourceName = catalogue_poly.sourceName
LEFT JOIN catalogue_id_master
ON catalogue_master.sourceName = catalogue_id_master.sourceName
WHERE
degrees(acos(cos(radians(90-%s))
*cos(radians(90-catalogue_master.DecWcent_deg))
+sin(radians(90-%s))
*sin(radians(90-catalogue_master.DecWcent_deg))
*cos(radians(catalogue_master.RAwcent_hr*15-%s)))) < %s
AND catalogue_master.sourcename != %s
AND catalogue_master.photSigma >= 7.0
AND catalogue_head.update('DATAMAX', 1.0)id_master.artifactProb != 'Likely'
ORDER by dist"""

cursor = connection.cursor()
```